# Why does my Android device unlocks to a non-responsive black screen?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, screen, hardware

Device : Nexus 5, running a freshly installed Paranoid Android 6.0.3 ROM. Device is empty except for some system and a few Google apps.

Here is the loop I'm stuck in:

1. Pressing power button brings me to the lock screen which is just a swipe. Click sound is heard.
2. Doing nothing keeps me at the lock screen. Swiping up to unlock 
   immediately turns the screen black. Screen is unresponsive.
3. Pressing the power button again does nothing, except the click sound is heard again.
4. Back to step 1. Unable to enter into the phone.

This behavior is generally observed after like half an hour of phone usage, when phone gets heated even just a little bit. Phone behavior returns to normal in like 1-3 hours if left untouched.

**Note :** I was running Paranoid Android 4.6 since 3 years and this behavior started about a week ago. I installed the version 6.0.3 about a day ago to see if the update would solve the problem but it didn't. 
I even gave my phone for repair. I was told the power button on the chip has been replaced. But that didn't solve the problem so I gave it back. This time I was told sensor problem was there but here we are again.

Comment: Without respect to the problem persisting after the upgrade... Sounds like your launcher is somehow dead. Did you do a clean install when upgrading? Also, for now I assume you don't have anything important on the phone, so why not just flash a factory image and see what happens?

Comment: I would have to argue that I don't think it's the ROM's problem because as I mentioned I've had that particular ROM since 3 years and without any changes or tweaks being made for 3 years. The problem started just a week ago. I performed an upgrade (which was a clean install of the newer revision of the ROM and not an OTA upgrade ) just to see if it would solve the problem. So ROM should be fine I would say.

Comment: If I were you I'd connect the phone to the PC and observe the logcat output when the phenomenon occurs. That does sound like a hardware defect...

Comment: I had the proximity sensor (which turns your phone screen off when you place your phone on your ear to talk ) disconnected by a repair man (so was his suggestion). Still the problem persists.
@AndyYan I think the process to install a factory image is more complex than installing custom ROM. Can you provide me a source where I can find a clear step by step guide. I think I have to try this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/images

Comment: Getting the sensor disconnected got me out of the loop (I am able to enter into my phone always) but a sub-problem still persists. If I use my phone for sometime continuously or it gets even a little heated, screen blinks a few times. Screen will turn off, I'll unlock the device (and I'll get into my phone unlike earlier) and it'll turn off again. This will happen for a few minutes. Because of this I cannot use gaming apps or even medium apps like facebook and youtube.